# onResume Does Not Update ListView With New Data

Tags: android

I am trying to update a ListView on previous fragment after back button press. The onResume is called (verified with Toast) and the webservice runs (listView is displayed after it is cleared). The problem is that the ListView is still showing old values and not new value after accessWebService_getUsername is called. I verify the values from MySQL and even though the DB is updated, the ListView only returns old values.

```
          @Override
          public void onResume() {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             super.onResume();

                adapter.clear();

                getIMEI();
                accessWebService_getUsername(); 

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

          }
```

Update:

//ListView

```
ListView lv =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

adapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(), arrRequest_Contact, arrRequest_NameSurname, arrRequest_MessageCount, arrRequest_Time, arrRequest_Image);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

// Json

```
         private class JsonGetUsername extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            //Pending 01
           private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                this.dialog.setMessage("Loading Contacts, Please Wait");
                this.dialog.show();
            }

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
           try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
           }


           catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
          }

          private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
           String rLine = "";
           StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
           BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

           try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             answer.append(rLine);
            }
           }

           catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           return answer;
          }

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                //Pending 02
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                try{  
                    ListDrawer_getUsername(); //has ConnectionException (when it cannot reach server)
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check your connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
              }
         }// end async task

         public void accessWebService_getUsername() {
        JsonGetUsername task = new JsonGetUsername();
          // passes values for the urls string array
          task.execute(new String[] { "http://mywebsite/php/get_username.php?pIMEI="+IMEI});
         }

         // build hash set for list view
         public void ListDrawer_getUsername() {

          try {
           JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
           JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("username_info");

           for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            request_username = jsonChildNode.optString("Username");

           }

           accessWebService_getContacts();

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              System.out.println("Json Error Rooms" +e.toString());
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Rooms To Load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }

    }
```

UPDATE 2:
//ContactsAdpater

```
             class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
            {
                Context context;
                List<String> Request_Contact;
                List<String> Request_NameSurname;
                List<String> Request_MessageCount;
                List<String> Request_Time;
                List<String> Request_Image;

                ContactsAdapter(Context c, List<String> Request_Contact, List<String> Request_NameSurname, List<String> Request_MessageCount, List<String> Request_Time, List<String> Request_Image)
                {
                    super(c, R.layout.activity_contacts_single, R.id.textContact, Request_Contact);
                    this.context=c;
                    this.Request_Contact=Request_Contact;
                    this.Request_NameSurname=Request_NameSurname;
                    this.Request_MessageCount=Request_MessageCount;
                    this.Request_Time=Request_Time;
                    this.Request_Image=Request_Image;

                }


                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    View row=convertView;
                    if(row==null)
                    {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_single, parent, false);       
                    }

                    TextView txtContact = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textContact);
                    TextView txtNameSurname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textNameSurname);
                    TextView txtMessageCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textMessageCount);
                    TextView txtTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textTime);

                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView); 

                    txtContact.setText(Request_Contact.get(position));
                    txtNameSurname.setText(Request_NameSurname.get(position));
                    txtMessageCount.setText(Request_MessageCount.get(position));
                    txtTime.setText(Request_Time.get(position));

                    Picasso.with(context).load(arrRequest_Image.get(position)).transform(new CircleTransform()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(imageView);                        

                    return row;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It's unclear from this code what data the adapter object can see.  Just because the data is coming down properly, doesn't mean it's getting routed properly into the adapter object.
Consider updating with more code/methods.

Comment: @FishStix - I did an update with code

Comment: When you construct the adapter, it looks like you're passing in the current state of the data.  With the other data (network) accessing methods, it doesn't look like you're passing in any of the updated state to the adapter.

Comment: how do you propose I proceed? I tried to re-set the adapter on onResume, doesn't work

Comment: You might be re-setting the adapter.  But then I wonder if the listview is still pointing to the original adapter?  Might be good to add some "setContact" "setSurrname" methods to the adapter, calling "notifyDataSetChanged" afterwards

Comment: Could you post your ContactsAdapter code please?

Comment: @KarenForde - I have posted the ContactsAdapter on UPDATE 2.

Comment: @user3560827 Thank you, please see below answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked, thanks to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to override the `clear` method in your ContactsAdapter to actually clear the lists you are storing your data in.

It looks like you'll need to clear all your lists, so if you add this to ContactsAdapter, your code should work as expected:

```
@Override
public void clear() {
    super.clear();

    Request_Contact.clear();
    Request_NameSurname.clear();
    Request_MessageCount.clear();
    Request_Time.clear();
    Request_Image.clear();
}
```